# Actualizar item de lista c#

Tags: c#, lista, stored-procedure

estoy llenado un objecto del tipo `Celda`

```
public class Celda
{
    [DataMember]
    public int celda_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_codigo_empresa { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_modulo_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int celda_orden { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_categoria_nombre { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_categoria_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string indicador_nombre { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string indicador_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string indicador_tipo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string indicador_descripcion { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<CeldaKeyVal> valores_celdas { get; set; }
}
```

Que contiene una Lista de Objectos tipo CeldaKeyVal

```
public class CeldaKeyVal
{
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_key_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_key_valor { get; set; }
}
```

Finalmente esto quedaria asi `List<Celda> celdas = new List<Celda>();`

Ocurre que para una `Celda` puede haber una lista de `CeldaKeyVal` y lamentablemente no tengo acceso a modificar el Stored Procedure que me trae estos datos, yo recibo algo asi :

```
CeldaId   CeldaKeyCodigo             CeldaKeyValue
1         Cod1                       Hola
1         Cod2                       Prueba
1         Cod3                       Test
2         C0d1                       Hola2
```

Yo recorro los resultado asi :

```
List<CeldaKeyVal> listaCeldaKey = new List<CeldaKeyVal>();
foreach(DataRow dr in dtCelda.Rows) 
{

    bool existe = celdas.Any(item => item.celda_id == Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaId"]));
    if (existe) {
        Celda celda_existente = celdas.FirstOrDefault(cus => cus.celda_id == Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaId"]));
        CeldaKeyVal celda_key_val = new CeldaKeyVal();
        celda_key_val.celda_key_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaKeyCodigo"]);
        celda_key_val.celda_key_valor = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaKeyValue"]);
        listaCeldaKey.Add(celda_key_val);
        celdas.First(d => d.celda_id == Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaId"])).valores_celdas = listaCeldaKey;
        //celda_existente.valores_celdas = listaCeldaKey;
    } else {
        listaCeldaKey.Clear();
        Celda celda = new Celda();
        celda.celda_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaId"]);
        celda.celda_codigo_empresa = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaEmpresaCodigo"]);
        celda.celda_modulo_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaModuloCodigo"]);
        celda.celda_orden = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaOrden"]);
        celda.celda_categoria_nombre = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaCategoriaNombre"]);
        celda.celda_categoria_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaCategoriaCodigo"]);
        celda.indicador_nombre = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorNombre"]);
        celda.indicador_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorCodigo"]);
        celda.indicador_tipo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorTipoCodigo"]);
        celda.indicador_descripcion = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorDescripcion"]);
        CeldaKeyVal celda_key_val = new CeldaKeyVal();
        celda_key_val.celda_key_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaKeyCodigo"]);
        celda_key_val.celda_key_valor = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaKeyValue"]);
        listaCeldaKey.Add(celda_key_val);
        celda.valores_celdas = listaCeldaKey;
        celdas.Add(celda);
    }

}
```

Si se dan cuenta Identifico si el item que estoy recorriendo existe, comparo por su `Id`. Esto funciona ya que identifica cual existe... Si existe obtengo el existente y modifico su campo valores_celdas que es mi `List<CeldaKeyValue>`, sin embargo esto no funciona para mi, una vez que salga de existir y yo creo una nueva Celda (porque tiene otra `Id`) limpio `listaCeldaKey` para tener una lista nueva para la Celda correspondiente. Sin embargo guarda siempre la primera, es como si no modificara la lista, y haciendo debug con puntos de interrumpción me di cuenta que al ejecutar `listaCeldaKey.Clear();` todos los valores que guarde dentro de mi `Celda.valores_celda` se pierden... ese es el error que tengo, que segun yo no deberia pasar ya que ya se los asigne a un valor determinado de mi Clase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema es un malentendido con la línea siguiente:

```
celdas.First(d => d.celda_id == Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaId"])).valores_celdas = listaCeldaKey;
```

Parece que estás bajo la impresión que estás copiando el *contenido* de la lista `listaCeldaKey` a `valores_celdas`, y que a partir de ese momento `listaCeldaKey` y `valores_celdas` son 2 listas diferentes.  Pero esto no es el caso.

Mas bien, simplemente estás copiando la *referencia* de la lista `listaCeldaKey` a `valores_celdas`.  De modo que cualquier acción que tomes sobre `listaCeldaKey` a partir de ese momento, incluyendo `listaCeldaKey.Clear()`, va a afectar a ambos. Porque, en efecto, ambas referencias apuntan a la misma instancia de la lista.

Una solución es reemplazar

```
listaCeldaKey.Clear();
```

... con ...

```
listaCeldaKey = new List<CeldaKeyVal>();
```

... para asegurarte que estás manipulando una instancia separada a partir de ese momento.

**Edición: Una mejor alternativa**

En lo personal, yo modificaría el código de esta manera para evitar tener que manejar una instancia de la lista fuera del ciclo.

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dtCelda.Rows) 
{
    bool existe = celdas.Any(item => item.celda_id == Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaId"]));
    if (existe) {
        Celda celda_existente = celdas.FirstOrDefault(cus => cus.celda_id == Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaId"]));

        CeldaKeyVal celda_key_val = new CeldaKeyVal();
        celda_key_val.celda_key_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaKeyCodigo"]);
        celda_key_val.celda_key_valor = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaKeyValue"]);

        celda_existente.valores_celdas.Add(celda_key_val);
    } else {
        Celda celda = new Celda();
        celda.celda_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaId"]);
        celda.celda_codigo_empresa = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaEmpresaCodigo"]);
        celda.celda_modulo_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaModuloCodigo"]);
        celda.celda_orden = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaOrden"]);
        celda.celda_categoria_nombre = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaCategoriaNombre"]);
        celda.celda_categoria_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaCategoriaCodigo"]);
        celda.indicador_nombre = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorNombre"]);
        celda.indicador_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorCodigo"]);
        celda.indicador_tipo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorTipoCodigo"]);
        celda.indicador_descripcion = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorDescripcion"]);

        CeldaKeyVal celda_key_val = new CeldaKeyVal();
        celda_key_val.celda_key_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaKeyCodigo"]);
        celda_key_val.celda_key_valor = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaKeyValue"]);

        celda.valores_celdas = new List<CeldaKeyVal>();
        celda.valores_celdas.Add(celda_key_val);
        celdas.Add(celda);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola! gracias por responder. La verdad es que tienes mucha razon, pero lo que me causa problema es que si Fuera de mi `foreach` solo declaro `listaCeldaKey` y le doy instancia en el ELSE de que no existe.... como lo hago en el IF que es donde existe? Si creo siempre una nueva Lista jamas tendre los datos que necesito.

Comment: @sioesi: Asumiendo que he entendido lo que estás haciendo, he agregado una alternativa simplificada de tu código.

Comment: Gracias @sstan ! Me salvaste, no habia entendido hasta ahora en que solo `copiando la referencia`! Un nuevo conocimiento, saludos!